# Not able to change UserAccountsDrawerHeader background

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to change the UserAccountsDrawerHeader background from light blue to another color in my Drawer but I'm not able to find a solution. Can anyone help me?

```
return Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text(sessionUsername),
        accountEmail: Text(mail),
        currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(gravatarUrl),
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Home'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.home, color: myColor),
        onTap: () {
          print("Going to home");
          //Close the drawer
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          //Navigate to home page
          //Navigate with avoiding the possibility to return
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomePage.tag);
        },
      ),

    ],
  ),
);
```

MyDrawer:

[image: MyDrawer]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you've not specified the `decoration` property, color is set to default primaryColor of theme. Use `decoration` property to set color.

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
    ),
    accountName: Text(sessionUsername),
    accountEmail: Text(mail),
    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(gravatarUrl),
    ),
),
```